# Tires for my husband's Mustang

Tags: tires

I bought my husband brand new tires about 3 years ago, he never put them on his car. Are they still good to put on a rim, or no?

Comment: Do the tires have any signs of cracking or dry rot?  Where were they kept?  Was it a temperature controlled area?

Comment: What is the date of manufacture of the tires?  (It is encoded on the sidewall.)  "Brand new" tires from tire stores are often not actually brand new.

Answer (score 9):

**The condition of the tires would depend on how the tires were stored**

Rubber can degrade under certain conditions.  If left outside, ultra-violet light can accelerate degradation of the tire.

If left on dirt with moisture underneath and in the weather they could also be in a degraded state.

Having tires wrapped and sealed if they are going to be stored for an extended period of time would assist in increasing their potential lifespan.

Keeping the tires in a cool and dry location is the second best circumstance.  Storing sealed is the best.

**Dry Rot** would probably be your primary concern after years of rubber/tire storage.

You can spot dry rot by feeling the surface of the tire.  It will be hard and brittle. The oils in the rubber evaporate and the chemical bonds degrade leaving behind a hard and brittle rubber that's dangerous to use.  Most claims state that 3-5 years without sealing in a tire in optimum conditions could leave a dry rotted tire behind.

[Here are some tips from a retailer regarding tire storage.](http://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=37)

***Image of a tire with mild dry rot***

[image]

Comment: He kept them in the closest,  thanks for the information..

Comment: Good deal!  Cheers !